# How to change different Virtual Network/Subnet for exiting Virtual Machine?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-vm-role, azure-vm

I have exiting virtual machine I need to change virtual network/subnet for this Virtual machine. I didn't found any option to change please help me out. Thanks..!

Answer (score 0):

As I know when the NIC is created in a VNet, then it cannot be moved to another VNet any more. So what you need to do is to create a new NIC in the VNet that you want to move the VM to and then attach the new NIC to the VM. Change the new NIC as primary NIC, then you can delete the old NIC. When all steps have done, the VM is already in the VNet you want.